# Printing Euro Symbol to PCL6 printer

Tags: universe, unidata, pick

I tried to print CHAR(128), U+20AC, etc. but none seem to print.  Does anyone know how to print the Euro Symbol to a Sharp PCL6 printer in Universe/U2?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dos the font you using have that glyph?

Comment: Yes, it printed 3 glyphs, also the printer is an HP LaserJet Pro 400.  I want to paste the picture here but I don't know how.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Euro symbol with ASCII 128 only applies with the correct 8-bit table because there is no consistency with ASCII beyond the 7-bit table. In other words if you output character 128 and you have the wrong character set assigned it will not print what you are expecting. A little research shows that the ISO 8859-1 able needs to be assigned.

You will need to consult the printer manual to determine how to change the assigned table.